# Deploy changes to PhoneGap Mobile App mark-up without deploying to market?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, jquery-mobile

I was wondering what the best approach on making changes to a PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile application with out deploying to each (apple and android)market.  Most of the changes I have been making recently have been strictly to the mark-up NOT the addition Phonegap features. I realize that if I added phoneGap functionality to a certain part of the markup this would have to change.
But on some pages that are strictly markup how can I deliever that content separately so that I wouldn't have to deploy the changes to the market each time?  Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  It appears that this wouldnt be possible due to ios terms of service:  Apples TOS - #2.7: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand what you're asking, but the app will have to be re-deployed (and approved for iOS) for _any_ changes to the app. Markup changes are changes to the app just as much as adding PhoneGap functionality.

Comment: I cant make any sense of this; clarify? If you have just made some mark-up revisions I don't even see the point of pushing the changes out, just seems like an inconvenience for everyone involved. I also don't get how you expect to be able to push the changes to the handsets without the market. Perhaps I've misunderstood?

Comment: I think I've understood now, see the answer!

Comment: Apple TOS #2.7 only applies if you're downloading code - *"Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected"*; it could be argued that you're downloading new content - as you're not adding in additional functions or anything native; you're downloading HTML akin to a web browser; i.e Chrome or Safari or any Social Networking app.

Answer (score 1):

(*If I understand this correctly, you've made some mark-up changes - perhaps new content, or layouts - to an existing phoneGap app and you want to roll the changes out to individual handsets without the market? You haven't made any functional changes though.*)

Unfortunately it's exactly the same as if you implemented a major functional change; you need to re-deploy and go through the market.

**However, due to the beauty of PhoneGap and web technologies - it may be worth implementing some form of feature to dynamically load new content to prevent this issue re-arising in the future. A simple automatic check upon app initialisation to check for new content could work; or a simple *"Fetch New Content"* button which launches an AJAX request to an external server would suffice.**

**This would mean content couldn't be hard-coded into an application - but using the Local Storage options (i.e *webSQL*) you could store the content and retrieve it upon load; then just update the storage upon update.**

By doing this you will satisfy any guidelines that require the app to be functional offline, whilst ensuring that you can push new content to the devices at will. You shouldn't fall foul of any app store guidelines either (that I know of); although as @ninjasense has mentioned in the comments - you will need to be careful about the fact it drags content from external sources*. It also gives you a reason to go through the market to update - after all, you've now added a major new feature. ;)

Hope this helps!

*Under no circumstances refer to it as a method for updating the app if you are going to market through iOS. That said; I notice that you're actually targeting Android - which this should be acceptable for. The primary issue is by allowing the code to be downloaded from an external source you could introduce security vulnerabilities, poor code or bugs in at a later date. (This would be possible as you're using PhoneGap and you, in theory, could push Javascript to the client handsets using this mechanism)

Apple TOS #2.7 only applies if you're downloading code - *"Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected"*; it could be argued that you're downloading new content - as you're not adding in additional functions or anything native; you're downloading HTML akin to a web browser; i.e Chrome or Safari or any Social Networking app. Hence why I would avoid referring to any changes as updates; merely content changes - and stress the fact you're downloading mark-up to display the content.

For those of you who can't access the app store approval guidelines - There's a [public PDF here](http://stadium.weblogsinc.com/engadget/files/app-store-guidelines.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the response...I'm pretty sure this would still break Apples TOS - #2.7: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Comment: I'll check out the Approval Guidelines in more detail in a bit; however looking at my post I'm going to guess that it's due to the 'updating' method bypassing the app store. This isn't going to be an issue if you make it clear that the app isn't updating, but downloading new content - i.e perhaps using a button that says "Load latest content"; like every social networking app out there. The only issue is if they deem the app to be -able- to auto-update as a PhoneGap app *can* using this mechanism. Although it's a moot point as I've just realised this Q is tagged as Android!

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving the content from your server and your markup changes donot affect the application locally (Meaning no code change to app is needed and markup changes are served from backend), then you are fine and you are not violating any terms. Infact, if you have to change the application, you WILL have to redeploy and you obviously have no way of violating the terms. So, there seems to be only one obvious way of doing it.